how to create a 10x10x10 rows table from 3 seperate 10-row columns in Excel?
I have 3 columns of input information (A, B, C) like the image below, each column has 10 variables.
Now I want to arrange each variable of column A corresponding to each variable of column B and C, the output will be similar to the table on the right

The result will come out as 10*10*10 = 1000 rows.
Is there any way to export the Output table like the one on the right, using Excel commands? The number of the variables in each column won't change, but the names might change, hence the request for using excel commands. Thank you very much!
I haven't thought of any solution yet. Someone suggested using Index Match - but I'm not sure how since I think Index Match is only an upgraded version of V-Hlookup.
I'm not a programming expert, just an occasional excel user, so please use as simple language as possible. Thank you!

@ScottHunter Sorry I can't think of any solution so no attempt from my side...

SO isn't a free coding service...

This concept is called "unpivot" - the opposite of making a pivot table. Try searching for a method to unpivot to get you started.

A quick search here for [excel] unpivot data: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+unpivot+data

Try: =LET(a,A2:C11,VSTACK(Table1[#Headers],TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,TOCOL(x&"|"&TOROW(INDEX(a,,y),1)))),"|",{1,2,3}),"|")))

Does this answer your question? Excel – Multiple Columns, Different Combinations

Does this answer your question? "unpivot" data from Excel

I didn't check Blackcat's link either. but I agree the OP will be better of searching the key word such as "Combination". I use =LET(list1, A2#, numList1, ROWS(list1), list2, B2#, numList2, ROWS(list2), list3, C2#, numList3, ROWS(list3), combinedList1, TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList3, "") & TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList2, "") & list1)), combinedList2, TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList3, "") & TOCOL(EXPAND("", numList1, 1, "") & TOROW(list2))), combinedList3, TOCOL(EXPAND("", numList1 * numList2, 1, "") & TOROW(list3)), HSTACK(combinedList1, combinedList2, combinedList3)) for this sort of issue.

=INDEX(A2:C11,MOD(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(1000)/{100,10,1},)-1,10)+1,{1,2,3})
Which creates a sequence of 1000,
divided by 100 in the first column,
divided by 10 in the second column,
divided by 1 in the final column.
It's wrapped in MOD to not exceed 10 in the last column.
You may have to change the cell references to your needs

Or very literally: ={"Exp country","Hub","Imp country"}&" "&MOD(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(1000)/{100,10,1},)-1,10)+1

Brilliant! For any number of rows and columns: =LET(data,A2:C11,r,ROWS(data),c,COLUMNS(data),INDEX(data,MOD(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(r^c)/r^SEQUENCE(,c,c-1,-1),)-1,r)+1,SEQUENCE(,c))).

Combine 3 Columns
Using IF/SEQUENCE (similar to this)
=LET(data,A1:C6,
    d,DROP(data,1),
    rc,ROWS(d),
    rt,rc^2,
    sa,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,rt),TAKE(d,,1))),
    sb,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,rc),
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,rc),INDEX(d,,2)))),,1),
    sc,TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,rt),TAKE(d,,-1)),,1),
    VSTACK(TAKE(data,1),HSTACK(sa,sb,sc)))



I2: =TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,9),A2:A4))
J2: =TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,3),TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,3),B2:B4))),,1)
K2: =TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(,9),C2:C4),,1)


Here is one more way of doing this, and the output you might be looking for :

The result will come out as 10*10*10 = 1000 rows.




• Formula used in cell E1
=LET(a,A2:C11,VSTACK(Tbl_1[#Headers],TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(
 REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(a)),LAMBDA(x,y,
 TOCOL(x&"|"&TOROW(INDEX(a,,y),1)))),"|",{1,2,3}),"|")))



The keyword you need to search are "Combination" and "Cartesian Product", my goto post is this one: Formula to Concatenate All Combinations of Values Two Columns Without VBA
You just need to find all combinations of list1 and list2, you will get 10 * 10 rows, let's call them list_12. then find all combinations of list_12 and list3, then you will get (10*10) * 10 rows.
To do is in one formula, you can use
=LET(
    list1, A2:A11,
    numList1, ROWS(list1),
    list2, B2:B11,
    numList2, ROWS(list2),
    list3, B2:C11,
    numList3, ROWS(list3),
    combinedList1, TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList3, "") & TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList2, "") & list1)),
    combinedList2, TOCOL(EXPAND("", 1, numList3, "") & TOCOL(EXPAND("", numList1, 1, "") & TOROW(list2))),
    combinedList3, TOCOL(EXPAND("", numList1 * numList2, 1, "") & TOROW(list3)),
    HSTACK(combinedList1, combinedList2, combinedList3)
)


One of the techniques used is  EXPAND("", 1, numList2, "") & list1. this is to repeat list1 horizontally 10 times.
Details in this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os8Yo3RiAVw
